# Stop UDP SocketServer

Tags: python, multithreading, socketserver

I'm creating an UDP SocketServer, and I would like to shutdown if I'm receiving a close message from the client side than I would like to close the UDP connection.

As I received the message the `Begin` will be displayed, but the `Finished` is not displayed. How can I exit from this thread?

```
class MyUDPHandler( SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler ):       
    def handle( self ):
        data = self.request[0].strip()        
        dic = self.string_XML_to_dic( data )
        if( dic['Cmd'] == str(UDPConst().SHUT_DOWN )): 
            print('Begin')           
            self.server.shutdown()
            print("Finished")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    HOST, PORT = "", prop['udpport']
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer( ( HOST, PORT ), MyUDPHandler )    
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html states this for shutdown() "Tell the serve_forever() loop to stop and wait until it does". How long are you waiting for it to perform its cleanup and shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not running the server in it's own thread (you need to inherit `ThreadingMixIn` for that), you can not use `shutdown` as it will cause a deadlock. From the function document comment in the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py):

> Blocks until the loop has finished. This must be called while
>   serve_forever() is running in another thread, or it will
>   deadlock.

Comment: So How can I shutdown the UDP server?

Comment: @KicsiMano Put it in its own thread, by letting `MyUDPHandler` also inherit from `ThreadingMixIn`. It's all in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Step 1 - Create a global object
global_object = dict()

# Step 2 - Create a function that will receive kill, Control-C signals
def stop_listener(*args): 
   global_object['listener_server'].shutdown()

# Step 3 - Assign kill, and Control-C signal to function=stop_listener
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT , stop_listener)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop_listener)

# Step 4 - Create UDP Server in usual way, and save a reference in global_object
server = socketserver.UDPServer(...)
global_object['listener_server'] = server
server.serve_forever()
```

**Explanation:**

- When Control-C is pressed or when kill is sent to pid -- function
  = stop_listener gets called.
- function=stop_listener, then calls shutdown on the UDPServer reference. -
- this helps clear listener.